# cordova - Failed: q is not supported

Tags: cordova, npm, module

When I build cordova this message view:

> Using "requireCordovaModule" to load non-cordova module "q" is not supported. Instead, add this module to your dependencies and use regular "require" to load it.

How fix this problem?

PS. I updated npm before this build problem. So it was not problem buildings before update. Sorry my English))

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. On our build server I upgraded 1 package (`ionic-plugin-deeplinks` because it stopped working), now I'm getting this error. Looking at the cordova 9.0.0 changelog, they did change something with `requireCordovaModule` and removed the `q` module. The strange part is that I have the cordova version locked to 8.1.2, so this shouldn't be an issue. But it feels too big of a coincidence not to be related.

Comment: @AndreasGassmann how to solve this problm..?

Comment: I fix this problem.
So I uninstall cordova(npm uninstall cordova -g)
then install cordova old version(npm install -g cordova@8.1.1)

Answer (score 17):

Solved this problem by installing a lower version of cordova. Seems like every version of cordova that is > 8.1.1 breaks a number of plugins.

For instance, the plugin cordova-sqlite-storage failed to install with the following error message:

> Failed to install 'cordova-sqlite-storage': CordovaError: Using
>   "requireCordovaModule" to load non-cordova module "q" is not
>   supported. Instead, add this module to your dependencies and use
>   regular "require" to load it.

To solve that issue, I simply removed cordova by calling `npm uninstall cordova -g` and then installed it globally again with `npm install -g cordova@8.1.1`

After that fix, no more errors are getting displayed and cordova-sqlite-storage gets installed smoothly!!

> Installing "cordova-sqlite-storage" for android

Comment: @TatiOverflow Well in this case, it is.

Comment: Changing to cordova version of 8.0.0 I was able to install ios 4.5.4 which let me install all the plugins I needed

Answer (score 8):

**In my case the following sequence fixed that issue:

> Remove ios platform **ionic cordova platform rm ios**
>
> Remove android platform **ionic cordova platform rm android**
>
> Remove sqlite storage plugin **ionic cordova plugin rm
>   cordova-sqlite-storage**
>
> Install latest sqlite storage **npm package npm i
>   cordova-sqlite-storage@latest**
>
> Install sqlite storage plugin **ionic cordova plugin add
>   cordova-sqlite-storage**
>
> Add ios platform **ionic cordova platform add ios**
>
> Add android platform **ionic cordova platform add android**

Answer (score 2):

The following fixed the issue for me

```
ionic cordova platform rm ios
ionic cordova plugin remove de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-sqlite-storage
npm i cordova-sqlite-storage@latest
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage
ionic cordova platform add ios@5.0.1
ionic build
cordova build ios
```

Comment: If I remove appplant plugin the app stops working. Don't you have another workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Just run `npm i cordova-sqlite-storage` 
This would upgrade the plugin to the latest version in which this issue is already solved.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried this and still got the same error :(