# Using "requireCordovaModule" to load non-cordova module "q" is not supported

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

i'm build my android application with ionic 3, try in cordova version 8.1.2 and 9.0.0 error like this :

> cordova build android
>   Using "requireCordovaModule" to load non-cordova module "q" is not supported. Instead, add this module to your dependencies and use regular "require" to load it.

how to fix it ?

Comment: I did this and got no errors anymore: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57773661/9982570

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same issue by doing many things check this  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55304065/cordova-error-using-requirecordovamodule-to-load-non-cordova-module-q-is-no)

also do 
1 - ionic cordova platform add android ( make any changes that appear in the cli to your config.xml )

2- make sure you have latest cordova and do ( npm cache clear --force )

3- make sure you have ( JAVA_HOME - AND SDK  CONFIGURED WILL IN SYSTEM ENVIRONMENT )

Answer (score 0):

The problem is now the Ionic Appflow build environment was updated to Cordova 9.

Maybe this can help you : https://ionic.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360021400494-Package-build-fails-with-error-CordovaError-Using-requireCordovaModule-